# Error with \pstThreeDCoor in pst-3dplot

Tags: pst-3dplot

I have a problem with this code

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pst-3dplot}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(-3,-2.5)(3,4.25)
\pstThreeDCoor
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

Error: 
! Undefined control sequence.
\XC@usec@lor ...\expandafter \c@lor@to@ps #1#2@@
\else \expandafter \expand...
l.9 \end
{pspicture}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type`I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

Do you anyone know what I do wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Very probably, you compile with `pdflatex`, which does not understand postscript. Try compiling with `xelatex`.

Comment: Thank you! It's working!

Comment: B.t.w;, from your error message, you seem to have a not so recent distribution. Am I wrong?

Comment: I have TeXLive 2017.

Comment: It's not so old, but perhaps you should update to TeX Live 2019.